# Getting the most recent data for each value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the data associated with the most recent  `curve_date` corresponding to each `tenor_years` value and am using the query below to do this. However, I am not getting the data as I would like it to be.

```
SELECT
  tenor_years,
  yield_pct,
  MAX(curve_date) AS "MostRecentDate"
FROM yc_node_hist
where fk_yc_update = 12
GROUP BY tenor_years, yield_pct
order by tenor_years
```

`SELECT * FROM yc_node_hist where fk_yc_update = 12` gives the data below:

```
id      fk_yc_update curve_date  tenor_years    yield_pct     
353443  12           2013-07-26       1           0.1436
353444  12           2013-07-29       1           0.1389
353445  12           2013-07-30       1           0.133
```

The data comes out as follows:

```
tenor_years   yield_pct   curve_date
1              0.0828     2014-05-14
1              0.0832     2014-05-19
```

I want to get something like:

```
tenor_years   yield_pct   curve_date
1              0.0828     2014-05-14
2              0.3232     2015-06-17
..
30
```

Thank You

Comment: What data are you expecting?

Comment: @Doolius For each `tenor_years` value such as 1,2,..30 I want the most recent `curve_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server offers `PARTITION`/`OVER` functionality for situations like that.

```
SELECT tenor_years,
        yield_pct,
        MostRecentDate
 FROM (
    SELECT
        tenor_years,
        yield_pct,
        curve_date AS "MostRecentDate",
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tenor_years ORDER BY curve_date DESC) N
    FROM yc_node_hist
    where fk_yc_update = 12
)M
WHERE N = 1
ORDER BY tenor_years
```

This produces a fast query with a projection, avoiding the need to join back to the original.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d129/5)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the yield_pct from the group by:

```
SELECT
  tenor_years,
  MAX(curve_date) AS "MostRecentDate"
FROM yc_node_hist
where fk_yc_update = 12
GROUP BY tenor_years;
```

And then join back on itself:

```
SELECT a.tenor_years, a.curve_date,a.yield_pct
FROM yc_node_hist a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    tenor_years,
    MAX(curve_date) AS "MostRecentDate"
  FROM yc_node_hist
  where fk_yc_update = 12) b 
ON a.tenor_years=b.tenor_years AND a.curve_date=b.MostRecentDate
ORDER BY tenor_years ASC;
GROUP BY tenor_years;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as
(SELECT
tenor_years,
--yield_pct,
MAX(curve_date) AS "MostRecentDate"
FROM yc_node_hist
where fk_yc_update = 12
GROUP BY tenor_years --, yield_pct
 )
select x.tenor_years, y.yield_pct, y.mostrecentdate
from x join yc_node_hist y on x.mostrecentdate = y.curvedate
```

CTE is one way to achieve it and the grouping on yield_pct has to be removed.

Comment: Thanks. But I get the error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
`

Comment: removed the `order by` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tenor_years,
       yield_pct,
       curve_date
FROM (
        SELECT tenor_years,
               yield_pct,
               curve_date,
               MAX(curve_date) OVER (PARTITION BY tenor_years) max_date
        FROM yc_node_hist
        WHERE fk_yc_update = 12
      ) [anon]
WHERE curve_date = max_date
ORDER BY tenor_years;
```